# Is it possible to use Get Sheet and filter by only created date?

Tags: smartsheet-api, smartsheet-c#-sdk-v2, smartsheet-api-2.0

I currently am using the get sheet method and then parsing through the sheet to get the rows created on today's date.  Is it possible to filter to only get the rows using the filter parameter?

If there is a curl (postman) example you can point to that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this cannot be done through the API at this time.